# i want to  check User Control is dock or not after adding user control to Form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, user-controls

i have make user control and inside that user control takes two buttons name dock and close respectively .

now i want to dock my user control to left when i clicks button dock and close my user control when i clicks  button close..

now it works fine.....
 but when i add my usercontrol to the toolbox by taking choose items....
then drag and drop my user control to form...
now i have chk on form move event if user control is dock or not...

(i am trying to use by making object of user control but doesnt helps.....)

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Container_User_Control.Container1 obj = new Container_User_Control.Container1();
            if (obj.Dock != DockStyle.Left)
            {
               obj.visible=false;


            }
            else
            {

              obj.visible=true;

            }

        }
```

Thanks in advanced....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why you are using a Mouse_Move event but if I understood your question right then:

When you drag your UserControl from the toolbox to the form, an instance of the usercontrol is created in the form designer code. Something like Container_User_Control1, so instead of using:

```
Container_User_Control.Container1 obj = new Container_User_Control.Container1();
if (obj.Dock != DockStyle.Left)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("none");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("left");
        }
```

use:

```
        if (Container_User_Control1.Dock != DockStyle.Left)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("none");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("left");
        }
```

Comment: No problem. I can see your question have been marked down. But I don't agree with it because if one can try and concentrate on your question, he gets the idea of what you are asking for.